# Property 'store' does not exist on type 'NextPageContext'

Tags: typescript, next.js

We are trying to move our NextJs project from JS to TS and while doing so I encountered following problem.

getInitialProps in my _app.tsx goes something like this:

```
    static async getInitialProps({ router, ctx, Component }) { 
    const { req, isServer, store, res, query } = ctx;
    let pageProps = {};
    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }
    return { pageProps, isServer, router, store };
  }
```

But when I try to access store in a functional component like:

```
SupportHome.getInitialProps = async ({ query, store, isServer }) => {
  store.dispatch(getCategory());
  return {
    isServer,
    store
  };
};
```

It throws the following error:
Property 'store' does not exist on type 'NextPageContext' and Property 'isServer' does not exist on type 'NextPageContext'
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: are you using any HOC component to pass `store` to the context?

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko I tried to extend NextPageContext, but it didn't work. Maybe I did it wrong, can you help me with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Basically NextPageContext has following fields defined in it's interface:

```
export interface NextPageContext {
    /**
     * Error object if encountered during rendering
     */
    err?: (Error & {
        statusCode?: number;
    }) | null;
    /**
     * `HTTP` request object.
     */
    req?: IncomingMessage;
    /**
     * `HTTP` response object.
     */
    res?: ServerResponse;
    /**
     * Path section of `URL`.
     */
    pathname: string;
    /**
     * Query string section of `URL` parsed as an object.
     */
    query: ParsedUrlQuery;
    /**
     * `String` of the actual path including query.
     */
    asPath?: string;
    /**
     * `Component` the tree of the App to use if needing to render separately
     */
    AppTree: AppTreeType
}
```

So I simply extended the interface in my _app.tsx. Something like this:

```
import {Store} from "redux";

export interface MyPageContext extends NextPageContext {
  store: Store;
  isServer: boolean;
}
```

And now whenever I have to use getInitialProps in any functional component I call it like this:

```
HelpDesk.getInitialProps = async (props: MyPageContext) => {
  const { query, store } = props;
  store.dispatch(getCategory());
  return { query };
};
```

Took inspiration from [here](https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/how-would-you-type-this~662bfdb5-b174-4503-94a6-e6ad83bca204)

Answer (score 0):

Do this to see what is going on:

```
SupportHome.getInitialProps = async (something) => {
  console.log(something)
  //store.dispatch(getCategory());
  //return {
   // isServer,
  //  store
  //};
};
```

If this is what you see, then it looks like the properties you want are on the `props` subkey:

```
props: { err: xx, req: IncomingMessage { ...something }, res: ServerResponse { ...something }, pathname: '/ComponentName', query: {}, asPath: '/xyz/', AppTree: [Function: AppTree], store: { dispatch: [Function], subscribe: [Function: subscribe], getState: [Function: getState], replaceReducer: [Function: replaceReducer], runSagaTask: [Function], sagaTask: [Object], [Symbol(observable)]: [Function: observable] }, isServer: true }
```

You are probably passing the wrong object into this function, so the error is upstream.

```
SupportHome.getInitialProps = async ({props}) => {
  console.log(props)
  const { store, isServer, store } = props
  store.dispatch(getCategory());
  return {
    isServer
    store
  };
};
```

Comment: `props: {
    err: xx,
    req: IncomingMessage {
      ...something
    },
    res: ServerResponse {
     ...something
    },
    pathname: '/ComponentName',
    query: {},
    asPath: '/xyz/',
    AppTree: [Function: AppTree],
    store: {
      dispatch: [Function],
      subscribe: [Function: subscribe],
      getState: [Function: getState],
      replaceReducer: [Function: replaceReducer],
      runSagaTask: [Function],
      sagaTask: [Object],
      [Symbol(observable)]: [Function: observable]
    },
    isServer: true
  }`
Store is there but how to use it?

Comment: Is the error at run-time, or is it a TypeScript typing error?

Comment: Error is at run time. NextPageContext doesn't have store and isServer as a property. Rest are there. Basically what I want is to extend NextPageContext interface but don't know how to do it.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Solved my query and posted the answer. Thanks, Josh for the help